# Regex on JavaScript to accept only numbers with 2 decimals

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, regex

I'm trying to do a Regex in a JavaScript + ASP.NET web form to validate a TextBox to accept only positive decimal numbers, with a max of 18 digits and 2 decimals.

```
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    $(document).ready(function (e) {
                        $("#<%=txtQtt.ClientID%>").bind('keypress', function (event) {
                            var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,18}(?:\.[0-9]{0,2})?$");
                            var key = String.fromCharCode(!event.charCode ? event.which : event.charCode);
                            if (!regex.test(key)) {
                                event.preventDefault();
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <span class="label100">Quantity:</span>
                <asp:TextBox ID="txtQtt" runat="server" CssClass="txt200" MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
```

The code "works"(its only accepting numbers), but not letting me type a dot, and I want to him only accept **only one** dot.

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `\\.` in `RegExp` object:

```
var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,18}(?:\\.[0-9]{1,2})?$");
```

Or else you can use regex literal:

```
var regex = /^[0-9]{1,18}(?:\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/
```

Also better to use `[0-9]{1,2}` instead of `[0-9]{0,2}` after decimal point otherwise it will also allow `123.` as valid number,

Comment: Strange, still not letting me type a dot. =(

Comment: Can you provide a demo link on jsfiddle reproducing this problem.

Comment: in a form: [http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/), but now can't get working at all. Help! :P

Comment: Your regex lie must be: `var regex = new RegExp("^[0-9]{1,18}(?:\\.[0-9]{0,2})?$");` in the demo code.

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/1/) and still nothing, I even tried on FF, Chrome and IE. Is possible to JsFiddle not work here?

Comment: Your demo code is wrong. [See this working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/2/)

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/3/](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/3/) now I did more similar to the original(from asp.net), but nothing. (only saw your post after this one, checking whats wrong here)

Comment: Did you check my working demo? I can only assist for regex part. I don't know about `keypress` etc.

Comment: Are you still facing problem with regex or jquery code?

Comment: [http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/7/](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/7/) Fixed! Working only for numbers, when I try to type a dot or even a backspace, don't work.

Comment: This code is still not working correctly. [See this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nbcqnvsa/9/) You only get single character at a time not the full number at once.